# Best strategy for a magazine app

Tags: codenameone

I'm developing a Magazine app and trying to find the best strategy to optimize performance and stability. The app should be able to handle +100 pages and expect users to swipe between them fast and smoothly.

With all this in mind, this is what I've tried so far.

The basic structure would be using tabs, with tabs bar hidden, to allow user swipe. Since loading + 100 tabs with huge images would be a mistake, I always mantain three tabs: the current page, the previous and the following. With a selection listener I change the positions accordingly.

The way I load and dispose images as selection changes is the big deal here. The app downloads the images from Internet and cache them in FileSystemStorage. Those images are 768 x 1024. This is what I've tried with different luck:

- Simply retrieve the images from FileSystem everytime a new page is requested:

  ```
      if (FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(rutaImagen)) {                                
          try {
              int size = (int) FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getLength(rutaImagen);
              EncodedImage imagenPubli = EncodedImage.create(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(rutaImagen), size);
          } catch(IOException io) {                
          }
      }
  ```

  This has proven to be inefficient and risky in terms of memory usage. My iPad mini launch frequent low memory warnings, and end up killed by jetsam after a little while.
- Store the images in a WeakHashMap, so Images don't need to be constantly loaded form FileSystemStorage, which seems to be the cause of problems and too expensive. Only if they are garbage collected, the first method comes in action.
  This solution perfoms better, and the memory warnings are dramatically reduced, but are still there. After stressing hard the app, 15 or 20 minutes later jetsam jumps in and kill the app.
- Similar approach: instead of WeakHashMap, I have tried CacheMap. This has been the best solution for me so far. I have to push hard to see some memory warnings once in a while, and no crash so far. Still not enterily happy though, because I believe I should not see any memory warnings at all.

I talk about iOS only here because the app performs well on Android whatever method I use, and I have never got any Out of Memory there.

What do you think? Am I in the right path? Would you guys use a different approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear from the question where the magazine page is just an image. If so I would suggest using the [ImageViewer](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/ImageViewer.html) class as it was designed exactly with the use case of an infinite list of large images to swipe and zoom thru.

The general strategy with the `Tabs` seems like a good start if you need something more elaborate than images. If it doesn't perform well you can always substitute `Tabs` for something else.

Comment: It's gonna be something more elaborate actually. Browse left-right between articles, and up-down inside every article. I think that rule out ImageViewer.

Comment: But my concern, beyond the structure, is how to optimize memory usage. Simply loading from storage everytime a image is needed doesn't seem to be the best option.

Comment: Loading from storage when a UI is shown is probably pretty efficient as long as the image isn't HUGE.The main issue I can see is potential memory leaks in releasing the images but those are all fixable.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem. That's why I'm using CacheMap, so the images are not constantly released. Do you think this is the best way?

Comment: It is more complex than just using cache maps as dangling component references can pose a risk. Like everything in programming this looks like a good strategy but trial and error will always find issues that need refinement.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll follow this path and see if it suits for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should use the "let-it-be-done" approach. So far you have tried to code everything yourself, while codenameOne has many optimized way of doing it. The easiest way would be to use a MultiList, which will display your images (by using an UrlImage). The UrlImage will allow codenameone to handle the caching and else. Basically, the image will be loaded when viewed and placed in cache afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, but I have in mind something more elaborate. My answer to Shai tells a bit more